# Combining $regex and $or operators in MongoDB Bson for .net Core project

Tags: mongodb, bson

I need Bson format Mongo query for Dot net core project
for following query

```
"{\"$match\":{\"FloorID\":\"aabc5c02c3be4f7c9cc71ee8fdc0be14\",\"$or\":[{\"Name\":{\"$regex\":\"^door$\",\"$options\":\"i\"}}]}}"
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got It. Thanks

```
"{\"$match\":{\"FloorID\":\"aabc5c02c3be4f7c9cc71ee8fdc0be14\",\"$or\":[{\"Name\":{\"$regex\":\"^door$\",\"$options\":\"i\"}}]}}"
```

Answer:

```
new BsonDocument{ 
             { "$match",new BsonDocument("FloorID", floodId).Add("$or",new BsonArray { new BsonDocument("Name", new BsonDocument { { "$regex", "^door$" }, { "$options", "i" } })})},
            },
```